# Diaspora server auto start when system start up in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, command

To start Diaspora sever, always need to cd to the /home/diaspora, then run ./script/sever
My server(Ubuntu 11.10) everyday restart. I want to configure the server(Ubuntu 11.10) to allow diaspora server start up whenever my server is up. How to do it?

I use Ubuntu version 11.10 to set up my diaspora server.

Answer (score 2):

**Good solution:**

You can write an init script to start each time the server boots up and shut down gracefully when the system goes down.

Ubuntu uses a different init system than most other Linux distributions, so I can't help you with that, but this page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto might be a good start.

**Easy solution:**

Log in as user you run diaspora as, open crontab editor (`crontab -e`), scroll to the end and enter:

```
@reboot cd /home/diaspora; ./script/sever
```

Then press `Esc` and type `:wq` to save the changes. That should do it.

Comment: It fail to auto start my diaspora server after my server reboot..

Comment: sorry, it was reboot, not restart. please try that